# fbconnect include not found by xcode

Tags: include, fbconnect, duplicates

when the following include is added to my project, xcode fails to find it:

## import "FBConnect/FBConnect.h"

i have added the facebook src directory to the header include path and the user header include path in the project and target settings.

when i change the include to #import "FBConnect.h" the file is found, but i get a duplicate symbol error when building: ld: "duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SBJSON.jsonParser in ..."

i am unclear on why the initial FBConnect/ is needed for the include, when all the source files are under the src directory, and either xcode or facebook's directions seem to be faulty, as that approach fails

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Facebook API more or less say:

- Copy the Facebook SDK into your Xcode project:

  - This can be done a number of different ways, but the easiest way is to just drag the src folder from the local Git repository for the SDK (e.g. ~/facebook-ios-sdk/src) into the app XCode project.
  - Expand src folder
  - Expand facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeproj Facebook SDK project
  - Drag and drop the "FBConnect" folder from the Facebook SDK project into your application's project.

I solve it like this: delete the folder src xcode project and asks "Remove References only" or delete.
Choose remove references, compile without problems.

Only you have the FBConnect folder in your project. ;) luck